# Do recent kernels have minimum memory requirements during startup?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, startup

I'm trying to upgrade the software on a very old computer: a Pentium MMX with 16 megabytes of RAM.  It's currently running a 2.4.37.11 kernel.

I've configured a minimal non-modular 4.14 kernel that does everything the 2.4 kernel does and tried booting from it.  Booting using LILO produces the following output:

```
boot: gentoo-4.14.3
Loading gentoo-4.14.3.................................
BIOS data check successful
```

At this point, the screen blinks briefly and then the system freezes.

If I add another 32 MB of RAM from another system, the 4.14 kernel boots fine, and `free` shows the kernel using a little over 4MB of RAM.  Does the kernel require a certain minimum amount of RAM during startup?

Comment: How big is your initrd?

Comment: Don't have one.

Comment: Statically compiled kernels can get pretty big, how large is your uncompressed kernel image?

Comment: @GracefulRestart, if I'm reading the dmesg output correctly, it's about 3 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent kernels don't have a minimum memory *requirement* (or if they do, it's well under 16 MB).  What they have is a minimum memory *address*.

For most of the kernel's early history, the x86 kernel defaulted to loading at physical memory address 0x100000, just above the specially-treated first megabyte of RAM.  Starting with the 2.6 series, the ability to set a different loading address was added with the `CONFIG_PHYSICAL_START` configuration symbol, and with 2.6.31, the default was changed to the 16MB mark to work around various hardware issues.

So, the crash is due to the system attempting to load the kernel at physical address 0x1000000, which is just beyond the top of memory.  As you can imagine, this doesn't work well.  The fix, depending on the kernel version, is to change either `CONFIG_PHYSICAL_START` (called "Physical address where the kernel is loaded" in the configuration menu), or the related `CONFIG_PHYSICAL_ALIGN` (called "Alignment value to which kernel should be aligned").